# ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'src'

Tags: python

I have the following project tree:

```
ADD_D
 |
 --SRC
    |-- units
    |-- config
    |-- app.py
    |-- __init__.py
```

I built the project via `pycharm`.
Under `pycharm` the application run without any error.

when running from terminal (I opened the terminal under `src` folder)

```
python app.py
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'src'
```

Why I can run the application via `pycharm` without any error, 
but can't run it via terminal ?

how can I fix it to run via terminal ?

I'm using `python 3.6.8`

Comment: Maybe try to remove the line where you import src

Comment: Try moving `app.py` up a directory

Comment: You can also try to run `app.py` from your root directory. So try `python SRC/app.py` from the directory `.../ADD_D`.

Comment: Try run the project with `PYTHONPATH=.. python app.py`. I suspect it works in PyCharm because the root folder was added to path so it can then find `src`. What @wychmaster wrote should also work.

Comment: Python file will only add file dir to `sys.path`.  The result is: python file can only find custom packages or modules in 'SRC'. You should  move `app.py`  up a directory. Or, you should add `ADD_D` to `sys.path`